# Spring Batch strategy

Tags: spring-batch

The high level requirements are as follows:
I have an input table(INPUT) from which I should read data, send it to an external service for validation and update the validation response in an Output table. Based on the various samples, I have implemented this one.

But, the input table is in flat structure. i.e, for ex: a Student table which has multiple exam results for a student in a table. When I send it for validation, I have to retrieve all the records of a student and send it for validation. 
One more issue is parallel processing. Hitting the external service will have some network latency and we would like to have parallel processing for reading, processing and writing or for processing and writing.

I would like to know about the feasible Readers, Writers and processors where this could be done.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to create a Reader which will read your data from the table. A single element (named E for the rest of my explanation) produced must able to be send to your validation service.

Then write a Processor that take have the previous parameter E. It calls your validation service. THe result of the validation will be the output of your processor (named O).

Finally, create a Writer that will take a O as a parameter and which role is to write the final data to the database.

Parallel processing will be done via Spring configuration, using a [ThreadPoolTaskExecutor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html). The important part is to write your Reader, Processor and Writer in a thread-safe way.

For better performances, you should also check the parameter *commit-interval* (on the Writer), and if you use Hibernate, check its batch capacities (I usually find the best performance by doing batch inserts/updates of 25-30 requests).